# Cannot use hibernate EHCache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I write web application using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and
I try to implement caching entities in my application using Hibernate EHCache.

But when I call method findAll() from repository I get an error.
I don't know what is the reason. Cachable collections are loaded lazy? I see here AbstractLazyInitializer but documentation of ehcache doesn't say nothing about lazy initialization.
What can be the reason?

```
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError
org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.nonstop.NonstopAwareEntityRegionAccessStrategy.get(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.hibernate.engine.internal.CacheHelper.fromSharedCache(CacheHelper.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.getFromSharedCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:651) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:997) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
            at com.myapp.model.ProductEntity_$$_jvstdbe_0.getType(ProductEntity_$$_jvstdbe_0.java) ~[classes!/:2.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.ProductTO_ProductEntity_ObjectFactory2345936633623123484334959983$4.create(ProductTO_ProductEntity_ObjectFactory2345936633623123484334959983$4.java) ~[orika-core-1.
    5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.getInstance(InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.java:55) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:66) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:254) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.mapElement(MapperFacadeImpl.java:802) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.mapAsCollection(MapperFacadeImpl.java:626) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.mapAsList(MapperFacadeImpl.java:424) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
            at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.mapAsList(MapperFacadeImpl.java:711) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
```

My entity looks following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(
        usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE,
        region = "com.myapp.model.ProductEntity"
)
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    public ProductEntity() {}

    public ProductEntity(String name, String description, Double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // getters && setters
}
```

My file application.properties:

```
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# Database PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Cache
spring.cache.ehcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=false
```

and ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    />

<cache name="com.myapp.model.ProductEntity"
       maxElementsInMemory="500"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="30"
       timeToLiveSeconds="60"
       />

</ehcache>
```

Comment: Can we see the repository code?

Comment: I forget write that I use JpaRepository and findAll() is a default method implemented by Spring Data.